# IE Problem : Transparent div above a picture doesn't trigger the CSS:hover

Tags: internet-explorer, html, hover, transparent

Here is the problem : I want to create reactive zones on a image using transparent div, but the following code doesn't work on IE (tested on Chrome) : the background-color of the div "hover_zone" doesn't change at all.

The problem is due to the background-color set to transparent. Use any valid color like #FFF and it works (it seems IE thinks like: it's transparent, it doesn't contain anything, let's not display it).

```
<html>
<body>

<style type='text/css'>

#hover_zone{
    background-color:transparent;
    visibility: visible;
    position:absolute;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    left:10px;
    top:10px;
    z-index:1000;
}

a:hover #hover_zone{
    background-color:#0C0;
    visibility: visible;
}

</style> 

<div id="container">
  <img src="http://ptaff.ca/blogue/wp-content/uploads/noir_black.png" />
  <a href="#"><div id="hover_zone"></div></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help!

Cheers!

Comment: I think the div is displayed, but it only triggers the hover event for portions that are not transparent. If I add a border to the div, then hovering over the border triggers the event, and if I put some text inside the div, then hovering over the text triggers the event.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this exact problem and fixed it with this style:

```
div#hover-zone { background:transparent url('../images/spacer.gif') 0 0 repeat; }
```

where spacer.gif is a 1px transparent gif.

hope this helps.

Comment: Blech ... I haven't used a spacer.gif in years. But this is the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: Thank you! I've been tracing an issue for days which turned out to be this one and your solution worked. Maybe worth mentioning that the image doesn't really have to exist for this fix to work. As long as the url() property is not empty, IE will display the div, regardless of whether the property is a url to an image or not.

Comment: It is 2013 outside and I'm still forced to make this ugly hack, 'thank you' IE8.

Answer (score 2):

**user filter for ie**

```
   background-color: #ffffff;  /* the background          */
   filter:alpha(opacity=50);   /* Internet Explorer       */
   -moz-opacity:0.5;           /* Mozilla 1.6 and below   */
   opacity: 0.5;               /* newer browser and CSS-3 */
```

Comment: As I said, "The problem is due to the background-color set to transparent. Use any valid color like #FFF and it works"

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, and my solution was to make the element have a "real" background color, but have zero opacity. Unfortunately, there is no "good" crossbrowser way to make that happen, but since I happened to need the element be partially transparent on hover, that was a *de facto* non-issue, so this solution worked well for me. It may not be right for you, but perhaps it will help others so I'll post it anyway.

```
.hotspot
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF; /* will be visible upon hover */

    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"; /* IE 8 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* IE 5-7 */
    -moz-opacity: 0; /* Netscape */
    -khtml-opacity: 0; /* Safari 1.x */

    opacity: 0;
}
.hotspot:hover
{
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)"; /* IE 8 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* IE 5-7 */
    -moz-opacity: 0.7; /* Netscape */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.7; /* Safari 1.x */

    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the 'img' inside the 'a' and use 'span' for the 'div' (blockelement not allowed in inline)

```
<style type='text/css'>

#hover_zone{
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    left:10px;
    top:10px;
}
a:hover #hover_zone{
    background-color:#0C0;
}

</style> 

<div id="container">

  <a href="#"><span id="hover_zone"></span><img src="http://revaxarts.com/portfoliodata/fotobox/screenshot.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```