# mouseEvent not firing for a div overlapping with an image

Tags: javascript, image, html, mouseover

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE Problem : Transparent div above a picture doesn't trigger the CSS:hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771717/ie-problem-transparent-div-above-a-picture-doesnt-trigger-the-csshover)

Hi,
Am facing issue with mouseover and mouseout event for a div which is overlapping with a picture. I want to show hotspots(highlighted and clickable area) over some parts of an image. For example, there is a picture of boy and his face has clickable square area over it like in facebook. Am using following code to achieve this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
      <html>
     <head>
       <title>test.html</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
       <style type="text/css">
         .mouseOutClass {
            border:  1px dotted #74CFFA;
          }
         .mouseOverTextClass {  
           cursor: pointer;
           border:  1px solid #74CFFA;
           background-color: #ffeaab; 
           filter:alpha(opacity=60);
           -moz-opacity:0.6;
           -khtml-opacity: 0.6;
           opacity: 0.6;
          }
      </style>

     <script type="text/javascript">

    function highlightBox(obj, show) {
      if (show) {
            obj.className = "mouseOverTextClass";
      } else {
        obj.className = "mouseOutClass";
      }
}
</script>
    </head>
     <body>
    <div  style="height: 100%;width: 100%;">    
        <div >
            <div style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; height:150px; width:150px;"
                class="mouseOutClass" onmouseover="return highlightBox(this, true);" onmouseout="return highlightBox(this, false);" >
            </div> 
            <div style="position:absolute; left:200px; top:100px; height:200px; width:200px;"
                 class="mouseOutClass"  onmouseover="return highlightBox(this, true);" onmouseout="return highlightBox(this, false);"   >                       
            </div>
            <img src="images/about.jpg" />
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

The highlightBox method just changes the class of the div which draws a border and changes bgcolor and opacity of the div.
The mouseover event is working fine in all browsers other than IE9. In IE the mouseover event is not fired if the mouse is over div where it is overlapping with picture. Am using HTML5 doctype for the page.

Update: the mouse events works if I draw a table in the div. however, the event will fire only on those places where there is a text in the table. Seems to me that mouse event does not work in empty div in IE9.. Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

add a z-index:100 to the div style

Comment: I already tried that but it does not work.

Comment: you also have to close all those divs you are opening, and if this is the exact code you're using, you forgot to close the style quote too

Comment: Sorry that is a typo. Am closing all Div elements and quotes in my original code

Comment: I have now pasted the whole code.