# Why does IE10's span require the presense of a background for click events?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, internet-explorer-10

See the two cases below. Mind you that this is only an issue in IE10

**Case 1**

```
<span onClick={this.doWork} style="display:inline-block;background:transparent;width: 100px;height:100px;line-height:100px;text-align:center;">case 2</span>
```

**Case 2**

```
<span onClick={this.doWork} style="display:inline-block;background:#fff;width: 100px;height:100px;line-height:100px;text-align:center;">case 2</span>
```

**Problem**: Refer to case 1. Only the text is clickable but not the span element itself.

**Solution**: Now refer to case 2. The entire span is clickable after adding a background to the span element.

**Question**: Why does IE10 require a CSS background to make the element itself clickable? I would still like to use a transparent background.

- Click event is being handled by react.

Comment: [Maybe related?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771717/ie-problem-transparent-div-above-a-picture-doesnt-trigger-the-csshover) - same solution (transparent repeated background image) might work

Comment: @JamesThorpe A transparent image does work. I suppose it's just one of MS's magic features.